# Struggling to use geom_ribbon for data in tidy format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 series that I would like to make a colored line plot of. Between two of the series, I would like to draw a shaded gray region. The data is in tidy format

This is what I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
#set up some random data
set.seed(1234)
A <- rnorm(10) - 2
B <- rnorm(10) + 2
C <- rnorm(10)
idx <- 1:10

mytbl <- as_tibble(data.frame(idx,A,B,C))

#convert the data in tidy format
mytbl <- gather(mytbl, -idx, key = "type", value = "value")

#create the data for ymin and ymax for the ribbon
mytbl <- mutate(mytbl, lower  = ifelse(type == "A", value, NA),
                 upper = ifelse(type == "B",value, NA ))

#the plot doesn't throw an error but also does not produce what I would like to have
ggplot(data = mytbl, mapping = aes(x = idx, y = value, col = type)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill  = "grey70") +
  geom_line()
```

I understand that I have to provide `ymin` and `ymax` for geom_ribbon and this was the only way I could think of, but it doesn't seem to work...

The easiest way would be to spread the data and then give different columns for the ymin and ymax, but I was wondering if it is possible to keep the data in tidy format and still use geom_ribbon?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no pair of `lower` and `upper` values where not either of them is `NA`. Store the data.frame before the `gather` step and use the `data` parameter to pass it to `geom_ribbon`. Then this will be trivial.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, that worked! I just replaced mytbl <- gather(mytbl, -idx, -B, - A, key = "type", value = "value") and then used the same code. However, now the legend shows only the line in the middle (C); is there a way to make it show (and color) also the upper and lower limit lines? (B and A respectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original data is tidy in the context of `geom_ribbon` because fundamentally the lower and upper boundary are different variables. Your complicated code that tries to reproduce what you basically already had is a clear indicator that your approach is not tidy.

```
mytbl <- as_tibble(data.frame(idx,A,B,C))

#convert the data in tidy format
mytbl2 <- gather(mytbl, -idx, key = "type", value = "value")

ggplot(data = mytbl2) +
  geom_ribbon(data = mytbl, aes(x = idx, ymin = A, ymax = B), fill  = "grey70") +
  geom_line(aes(x = idx, y = value, col = type))
```

Comment: Indeed it was not clear to me at all that I can set the **levels** of the "type" variable as ymin and ymax. Thank you, this helped me.